# Highcharts prevent column overlapping

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have the next HighStock example: jsfiddle.net/qkjo3sLy/4/

The problem is that is overlaps me the columns with the same timestamp. I would like to have them one after another on the same timestamp slot.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your number of series is constant, you can change the [`pointPlacement`](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.column.pointPlacement) and [`pointWidth`](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.column.pointWidth):

```
plotOptions: {
  series: {
    pointWidth: 50,
    ...
  }
},
series: [{
  pointPlacement: -0.22,
  ...
}, {
  pointPlacement: -0.22,
  ...
}, {
  pointPlacement: 0,
  ...
}]
```

If you have a varying number of series, you can make a function for this of course.

**Working example:** http://jsfiddle.net/ewolden/qkjo3sLy/11/

Comment: That's a good idea. Anyway, I was thinking that there is a cleaner method to do this, but it's ok for the moment. Thanks!